# Optimize a sphere's position with Mistuba 3

Tags: python, optimization, graphics

As a simple experiment with [Mitsuba 3](https://github.com/mitsuba-renderer/mitsuba3) I want to use gradient optimization to find the best position of a sphere.

Looking at the scene params I have `s.to_world`, a `Transform4f`, and `s.bsdf.reflectance.value`, a `Float`.

If I try to follow the [Gradient-based optimization](https://mitsuba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/inverse_rendering/gradient_based_opt.html) tutorial, it fails if I use `s.to_world` instead of `s.bsdf.reflectance.value`:

```
Exception: Optimizer.__setitem__(): value should be differentiable!
```

If I try to follow the [Object pose estimation](https://mitsuba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/inverse_rendering/object_pose_estimation.html) tutorial, I can't figure out how to apply the transformation. A sphere doesn't have `vertex_positions` that I could transform.